# If a,b are separable and algebraic over an infinite field how do we show $\exists k \in K$ such that $K(a,b) = K(a+kb)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to know how to display this without any advanced Galois Theory or proving that there are finite intermediate fields.